# How to get items in outlook add-in js when changes updated in meeting through outlook calendar

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

after generating the meeting I want to change something in the meeting via outlook calendar and after changes are done on send I want to post the items in APi like title, end time, and start time.
for that I used **onAppointmentSendHandler** when clicking on send this event should fired but it doesn't work even its not called.
here is the code

```
async function onAppointmentSendHandler(event) {         
  const token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  const startDate = await getStartDate();
  const endDate = await getEndDate();
  const property = await getCustomProperty();
  if (property.meeting == "calloquy") {
    const response = await update_meeting(token, property);
    console.log("response onsend",response)
  }
}
```

is there any other way to doing it or other event handler we can use ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not as easy as one would like. There are manifest.xml updates, plus separate html/js files involved, separate from the Add-In itself.

Please see if https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34574586)